# Why APNS device token could not be generated on some device in production mode?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have developed a chat application with push notification service. I have tested it on development mode and adhoc mode . Every device is generating device token successfully. But in production mode, report comes that some of the device could not be registered to APNS . I don't know the reason why it is happening. Each and every device on which i am testing, successfully registered with APNS but some of the devices couldn't be registered. Anyone have idea about it? I am stuck and could not find the reason behind it . My code for registering to APNS is-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary   *)launchOptions
{

  [[UIApplication    sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound ];
  // Handle launching from a notification
  UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
  if (locationNotification) {
    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
  }

  //some other code//

  return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: (NSData *)deviceToken
 {
 globalManager.deviceToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];


 }

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:  (NSError *)error
 {
  globalManager.deviceToken=nil;
  NSLog(@"fail reg");
 }
```

Comment: why don't you take a look at the error which is passed into didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError? It will tell you the reason

Comment: Ok if i print that error in log. Then how could i know for each error in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrey pointed in the comments above, you should really examine error passed to you app delegate's `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`. It will likely contain the reason for the failure.

Reasons for such failure may range from users not allowing your app to use push notifications, to network problems, to something else.

Comment: This is my first app on apple store. Please tell me the way that how could i know the reason for that in production mode.

Comment: Well, how do you know that APNS registration fails in the first place? I assumed you have some sort of reporting; you can use very same reporting to pass exact error, too.

Comment: Ok, if this error occured from any of the above mentioned issues, What can i do to resolve it?

Comment: If the error is due to user not giving your app permission to receive notifications, you can try to change her mind by explaining why your app needs notifications (e.g. through some sort of a welcome/info screen).  Apart from that, I don't think you can do anything about it except ensuring that your app handles "no notifications" case and continues to run and as stable as it can.